# Conditional statements in SQL

Tags: sql

Is it possible to insert duplicate values into a database row only if a different column in the same table is unique? Thanks for your help.

database table setup:

```
login_time int(15) [unique key] | user_id int(15) | time_worked varchar(64)
```

This is my insert statment. 
What i need is to only insert if user_id or login_time is unique.
And to not insert if both user_id and login_time match another row in the database.

```
    INSERT INTO `ucm_user_timelog` VALUES (' . intval($user_id) .
        ', ' . $timeWorked . ', ' . $logInTime . ')
```

Comment: I hope the PHP variables don't confuse you too much. the insert statement is called from inside a PHP variable.

Comment: You should do a `SELECT` query first on the table ucm_user_timelog, and use PHP (assuming that is the server side scripting) to match whether or not the `$user_id` or `$logInTime` matches.

Comment: Yeah, i figured as much. i was just hoping that I could do this from the database end.

Comment: when you make your login_time as unique, then you can never have two rows that have the same login_time.

Comment: What database are you using? I mostly use Oracle, and in there I would do this (I removed the quotes for clarity): INSERT INTO ucm_user_timelog SELECT $user_id, $timeWorked, $logInTime FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ucm_user_timelog WHERE user_id = $user_id and login_time = $logInTime)

Comment: Okay just to clarify,
My goal was to insert to the database only if two field are unique. 
I did this via PHP instead of SQL.

Solution
`code
        $Qarray = array();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `ucm_user_timelog`';
        $q = qa($sql);
        foreach ($q as $row) {
            array_push($Qarray['user_id'], $row['user_id']);
            array_push($Qarray['login_time'], $row['time']);
        }
        if (in_array($logInTime, $Qarray['login_time']) && in_array($uID, $Qarray['user_id']))
        {
            //echo error
        }else{
        //inset statement
        }}`